# In Nifi, how do I get the HandleHttpResponse to return the reponse of the invokeHttp processor?

Tags: http, apache-nifi

Right now my flow is: input -> invokeHTTP -> handleHttpRespone

My invokeHTTP makes a POST request and returns a message. However, it still responds with the payload I sent to it using Postman. Do I need to use ReplaceText or some other processor before the response handler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@DamienScott invokeHttp should return the response for the post to the Flow file which goes to success route.  In the configuration of InvokeHttp is "Put Response Body In Attribute" which by default should be empty to allow the response to go to the FlowFile.